# GWT inject CSS on runtime

Tags: css, gwt, code-injection

I'm using gwt 2.3.0 in my project.
I need to change my css source:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="gxt/css/gxt-all.css">
```

during run time (i want to decide which file to use on onModuleLoad method).
what is the best wat to do so?

Answer (score 12):

To inject a CSS file, you need to proceed in a similar way as  `ScriptInjector` does for javascript file :

```
/** Load CSS file from url */
public static void loadCss(String url){
    LinkElement link = Document.get().createLinkElement();
    link.setRel("stylesheet");
    link.setHref(url);
    nativeAttachToHead(link);
}

/**
 * Attach element to head
 */
protected static native void nativeAttachToHead(JavaScriptObject scriptElement) /*-{
    $doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
}-*/;
```

**@jusio:**

`StyleInjector.inject(...)` works with CSS content only :

```
StyleInjector.inject(".myClass{color:red;}");
```

Comment: Looks like I failed twice with this question (first providing wrong solution, second - forgetting to fix it). Thank you for posting correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using Elemental 2 on GWT 2.8.2 or J2CL:

```
 public static void loadCss(String url){
        HTMLDocument document = DomGlobal.document;

        Element link = document.createElement("link");
        link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        link.setAttribute("href", url);

        document.getElementsByTagName("head").getAt(0).appendChild(link);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this JSNI method and call this method form onModuleLoad() of GWT by giving url (path of your css) as argument based on your requirement.

```
public static native void loadCss(String url)/*-{
    var fileref=document.createElement("link");
    fileref.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/css");
    fileref.setAttribute("href",url);
    $doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}-*/;
```